# cp: cannot create regular file: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions, php, cp, file-copy

I am running a PHP script on my Apache server and from the script I need to copy some files (to run a Bash script that copies files). I can copy to a directory `/tmp` with no problems, but when I want to copy to `/tmp/foo` then I get this error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/tmp/foo/file.txt': Permission denied
```

even though the permissions for the directory `/tmp` and `/tmp/foo` are set to the same value.

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: can you share the result of `whoami` and `ll /tmp`

Comment: @SivaPrasath `/tmp` is always for root by default! the two commands results is not related in this case, becase `/tmp` has all the permissions for all users

Comment: @HamidYousefi yes, `tmp` is for root, but not for `/tmp/foo` OP might be running the script as a different user with `/tmp/foo` belongs to.

Comment: @SivaPrasath whoami is apache and ll /tmp returns drwxrwxrwx for /tmp/foo

Comment: @SivaPrasath Enforcing -what does it mean? ...but my problem has been solved by Hamid

Comment: @GorTeX check https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446586/9702260

Comment: Hello welcome. To make things easier in the future, when asked for clarification, please clarify by amending the question (not by adding a comment), show commands, and output in full. This will help us with answering you question more quickly. Thanks, and happy questioning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/tmp` Directory has all the permissions (read/write) for all users. but if you made `/tmp/foo` by your own account, it has its permissions just for you! if you want to make it writable for other users (or programs) change its permission with this command:

`chmod 777 /tmp/foo`

If you have any other files inside this directory from before, add `-R` flag to above command.

**Update:**
Use this command to change `/tmp/foo` owner from your own to apache default user:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /tmp/foo -R`

also please check your apache2 configuration to see which user it has for running the php scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesnt work. I have set the permissions for /tmp/foo to 777 and still I get the same error. When I run the script as a normal user then it is okay. But problem is when I run it from a php script

Comment: Can I see your scripts please!? and are you using php or php-fpm? your problem is, by default php using apache configured user for running scripts, while you made `/tmp/foo` by your own account! I will update my answer, check it again please.

Comment: php script: <?php  shell_exec(" bash /path/to/script.sh ) ?>  and script.sh is  #!/bin/bash cp /my/folder/file.txt /tmp/foo

Comment: How can I find which user apache uses for running php scripts? When I put to my php script bash command whoami then I get "apache"

Comment: can you give me the output of this command: ```ls -alh /tmp | grep foo``` if the directory has `foo` name.

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 4 apache apache foo

Comment: just `rm -rf /tmp/foo` and then add this line before your `shell_exec(" bash /path/to/script.sh )`

This one:
`if (!file_exists('/tmp/foo')) mkdir('/tmp/foo', 744);`
test it please.

Comment: Now it is working! Thank you very very much. Still dont understand why it didnt work before but I am glad it does now :)

Comment: I really became happy :) you had permission issue that I can't tell you exactly where it made problem. but now your problem solved ;)

Comment: permissions for the /tmp/foo now is d-wxr-x--T..havent seen that before

Comment: check this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/432699/what-is-the-t-letter-in-the-output-of-ls-ld-tmp